# Execute a PHP File Without the .PHP Extension on IIS

Tags: php, rewrite

How can I execute a PHP File Without the .PHP Extension on IIS server.
I have a clone script and in .htaccess file there are rewriterules as following.
But it doesn't work on windows 2008 server on IIS.

options -multiviews

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^users$ users.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
...etc

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file is specific to Apache Webserver.

You want to use IIS' alternative module called "URL Rewriting". You can find more info on how to create your rewrite rules in IIS here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/